# SAS Enterprise Guide UNIX WORK library - viewing files

Tags: unix, sas, enterprise-guide

How do I view the file below in Enterprise Guide (v 4.1 )?

```
%let libWORK=%sysfunc(pathname(WORK)); * work lib is on UNIX ;
data _null_;
    file "&libWORK./MYFILE.htm";
    put '<html>' /
        '   <head>'/
        '       <title> A Title </title>'/
        '</head> <body> some content </body> </html>';
run;
```

Comment: Bazil, would you consider cross-posting the same question to www.runsubmit.com ?

Comment: done - didn't realise this site existed!  Thanks Jay!  Goodbye Stackoverflow!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually - annoyingly - my previous solution didn't help.  SAS still applies a 'wrapper' to the HTML, destroying any header information (eg Javascript functions).

The following will fix it - basically run a dummy piece of code to create the reference in your EG session, then proceed to overwrite it with some pure html of your choosing!  The link will remain...

```
%let libWORK=%sysfunc(pathname(WORK)); * work lib is on UNIX ; 
ods html body="&libWORK./MYFILE.htm" ;
data _null_;
 file print;
 put "this will be overwritten! ";
run;
ods html close;

data _null_; 
    file "&libWORK./MYFILE.htm"; 
    put '<html>' / 
        '       <head>'/ 
        '               <title> A Title </title>'/ 
        '</head> <body> some content </body> </html>'; 
run;
```

Answer (score 0):

Got it!  eventually.

```
data _null_;
    file print;
    infile "&libWORK./MYFILE.htm"; 
    input;
    put _infile_;
run;
```